# Dot net assembly viewer?

Tags: .net

I have a dll that contains a dot net assembly - common intermediate language. The problem is that it's lacking documentation and I need to figure out the api like available classes, properties and methods, correct parameters to pass etc.

Whats the best way to do this. I need some sort of viewer/inspector but I couldn't find any.

Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try reflector. http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/

Its free :-)

**Edit**:
As of February 2011, its no longer free ...:(
[There are alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646707/something-better-than-net-reflector) like [ilspy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ilspy.ashx) or [JetBrains dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/).

Comment: Also note that it lets you look at the IL code AND translations to other Languages.

Comment: And don't forget to look for plugins. You can make it do practically anything you want except make coffee.

Answer (score 4):

Please try [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/). It is very good tool to view the assembly info.
[Assembly Analyzer](https://asmanalyzer.codeplex.com/) is another tool for analyzing the metadata and resources within a .NET assembly, as well as disassembling non-CLI executable files.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: `winget install --id icsharpcode.ILSpy`

Answer (score 1):

Having tried a bunch of them (CodeReflect, Dis#, JustDecompile, ILSpy, dotPeek), one thing I realised is that most decompilers don't show you code in a very readable fashion. ILSpy is good, except that everything seem to be so cluttered. There are almost no new line at all between class members.

In that respect [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) and [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) stand out. [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) looks more polished with a slightly better interface to work with, except that it comes with a web installer, and you have to register as well in the process.

They all have strength and weaknesses, but my choice would be [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) which do not force you to register. It also comes with handy Visual Studio shortcuts which makes the whole experience familiar (for eg `F12` to navigate to definition). With either of them you have a decent decompiler.

Answer (score 1):

JetBrains dotPeek works great and is free, highly recommend.