# Text property in a UserControl in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have a control with a inner TextBox. I want to make a direct relationship between the Text property of the UserControl and the Text property of the TextBox. The first thing I realized is that Text was not being displayed in the Properties of the UserControl. Then I added the Browsable(true) attribute.

```
[Browsable(true)]
public override string Text
{
    get
    {
        return m_textBox.Text;
    }

    set
    {
        m_textBox.Text = value;
    }
}
```

Now, the text will be shown for a while, but then is deleted. This is because the information is not written automatically within the `xxxx.Designer.cs` file. How can this behviour be changed?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You need more attributes:

```
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
[Browsable(true)]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
[Bindable(true)]
public override string Text { get; set; }
```

Comment: Don't forget to rebuild after adding the attributes for the changes to appear in the designer.

Answer (score 15):

Reflector is a crucial tool for a .NET developer.  It is immediately obvious what you need to do when you use it to look at the UserControl.Text property:

```
[Bindable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never), Browsable(false),
 DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
public override string Text
{
    get
    {
        return base.Text;
    }
    set
    {
        base.Text = value;
    }
}
```

Ho showed you what you need to do to cancel these attributes, too bad he didn't show you how he found out.  Reflector <strike>is</strike> was free, download it from redgate.com or check the alternatives here : [Something Better than .NET Reflector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646707/something-better-than-net-reflector)

Comment: Hans, +1 for the advice. However I have to accept Ho answer, as it is also correct and it was written sooner. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For serialization within the `InitializeComponent()`, all you need is the [DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerserializationvisibilityattribute.aspx):

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
```