# How to expose the Text property of a UserControl?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Text property in a UserControl in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881409/text-property-in-a-usercontrol-in-c-sharp)

How do I mark the `Text` property of a `UserControl` as browsable?

---

A .NET [`UserControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/97855yck.aspx) class has a [`Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7k5hkke.aspx) property.

Unfortunately the `Text` property of a `UserControl` isn't [***browsable***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute.aspx):

```
//
//
// Returns:
//     The text associated with this control.
[Bindable(false)]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
[Browsable(false)]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
public override string Text { get; set; }
```

In my `UserControl` I *want* to expose the `Text` property (i.e. make it "*browsable*") in the properties window. I tried blindly declaring it browsable:

```
[Browsable(true)]
public override string Text { get; set; }
```

and now it appears in the properties window, except now it does nothing.

I tried blindly calling `base.Text` to bring back the functionality:

```
[Browsable(true)]
public override string Text { get {return base.Text;} set { base.Text = value; this.Invalidate(); } }
```

and now the property does function at design-time, but the property value is not persisted to the `Form.Designer.cs` and it's `InitalizeComponent` code.

What is the *proper* way to expose the `UserControl` `Text` property so that it:

- is browsable in the properties window
- is functional
- is persisted in the form designer

*and, as a bonus*:

- know when it changes

Comment: Not quite an exact duplicate. My question was *how* (i.e. the proper way, as opposed to my random keyboard mashing) to make a property browsable. The other question is a property that already is browsable, but isn't being serialized.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're on the right track; just add `[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]`

To find out when it changes, override `OnTextChanged`:

```
protected override void OnTextChanged (EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("OnTextChanged(): eventArgs: " + eventArgs);  
    base.OnTextChanged(eventArgs);
}
```