# C# winform textbox.text doesn't change

Tags: c#, winforms

```
public partial class A : UserControl
{
  private string _x;
  public string X {
    get { return _x; }
    set { 
      this._x = value;
      this.textBox1.Text = this._x; 
  }
}
public partial class B : WinForm
{
   public B() {
     //Add usercontrol A to Groupbox1
     //Set A.X = "hello world"
   }
}
public class MainForm: WinForm
{
    public void button1_Click(....) { 
       B bForm = new B();
       bForm.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

At design time, I set the textbox1.Text="hello". In the Main Class, I have a button that will open a new form B and on that form B I have a group box to add this user control A and change the X property value = "hello world" but the textBox1.Text doesn't change on the UI. When I set break point after the set textbox1.Text = this._x, it shows the value did change to "hello world" but it's not reflected on the UI?

Why? And how to fix it?

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Do you want to change the text of textbox same as the X than you have to assign `this.txtBox1.Text = this._x;`

Comment: Do you use dataBinding?

Comment: No, I don't use databinding. Wonder why the set .Text directly doesn't work.

Comment: @user858931 Show your ` //Show Form B` code

Comment: @nikita I just updated it.

Comment: @user858931 Don't see your B constructor code, but keep in mind that your `X` property is serialized in `InitializeComponent` method and if you set `X` before `InitializeComponent` then it will be erased in `InitializeComponent` method.

Comment: It looks as if that value is overridden after you set it. I'd try to look for all the references to `textBox1` and put a breakpoint in every line where the Text property is changed (if there are such lines). If you don't find anything this way, I'd add a TextChanged event with a simple method with just a breakpoint in order to understand when/where the value is changed.

Comment: i'll have some other tests it tomorrow. Will post update later.

Comment: Have a look at this & it's a perfect solution:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881409/text-property-in-a-usercontrol-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is (since I don't see all code and it's all like guessing game 8)) - there is `InitializeComponent` method in `classB`. Since `X` property doesn't have `DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)` attribute it is serialized in `InitializeComponent` method with empty string - thus erasing previously explicitly set value.