# Serializing custom control's naming without DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute

Tags: c#, winforms, overriding

## Problem

I was trying to create a custom control which contains nothing but a label. However, I wanted the label's text to be changed to what the name property of the custom control has received at design time.

**This is what my custom control's class looks like:**

```
public partial class Tile : UserControl
{

     public Tile()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
     }

     [Browsable(true)]
     public override string Text { get => label1.Text; set => label1.Text = value; }
}
```

As you can see, I've overridden the UserControl's `Text` property in a way that it updates the Label's text too as soon as the `Name` is updated which in the end did not work. What happened was when I dragged the control from Toolbox to form the label got updated as expected but the moment I build the project, the designer got refreshed and the Label's text was lost.

---

## What I tried

- ### DesignerSerializationAttribute

  Going through Google I came upon a solution given at StackOverflow
  itself by Hans Passant that using
  `DesignerSerializationAttribute(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)`
  can solve the problem as  the value the `Text` property is given will
  be persisted in the initialization code which seems valid when it was
  getting lost at first (value didn't persisted and lost upon designer
  repaint).

  **So I changed my property like this:**

  ```
  [Browsable(true), DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
  public override string Text { get => label1.Text; set => label1.Text = value; }
  ```

Doing such change actually solved the issue and now it was working even If I build the project.

---

## What I found

Though my issue got solved but then I started to look for another way
to approach the same result.

While experimenting more with my code I found that If I create
another property that exposes the label's `Text` property and update
it using the **overridden** `Text` property it works exactly what it
was working using `DesignerSerializationAttribute`.

**Here what the new code looks like:**

```
   [Browsable(false)]
   public string LabelText { get => label1.Text; set => label1.Text = value; }

   [Browsable(true)]
   public override string Text { get => LabelText; set => LabelText = value; }
```

---

I wanted to know that

Why this works (even without `DesignerSerializationVisibility`):

**`Text`---->`LabelText`---->Label's `Text`**

I might be asking something very obvious right now but I've been reading about it since hours which made it a bit confusing for me .

Comment: That's because `Text` property of user control is marked as hidden (not serialized). In the second scenario, your new property is serialized and is keeping the text for future use.

Comment: Default behavior for a property is to get serialized, but explicitly [turned off](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2881855/17034) for the UserControl.Text property.  So LabelText gets serialized, [Browsable(false)] doesn't stop that, in effect preserving the Text property.  Sensible thing to do is just turn these attributes back on, also Bindable and EditorBrowsable.

Comment: @HansPassant I used `[Browsable(false)]` otherwise It would display two properties(basically duplicate) which do not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/UserControl.cs,242) of `UserControl`, you can see the `Text` property is marked as not serializable by designer, so basically the value of the property will be lost after you close the form:

```
[Browsable(false),
EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never), 
Bindable(false), 
DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
public override string Text {
    get {
        return base.Text;
    }
    set {
        base.Text = value;
    }
}
```

But in your alternative solution, designer will serialize `LabelText` property, and later will use its value to return as `Text`. That's why it works.

Comment: If only I looked at the source before posting I would've gotten my answer myself. Thank you for pointing this out.