# Reflector will not be free anymore. Any alternatives?

Tags: c#, .net, reflector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Open Source Alternatives to Reflector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425973/open-source-alternatives-to-reflector)

Since March, this tool is no longer free even for all its old versions. Any alternatives?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open Source Alternatives to Reflector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425973/open-source-alternatives-to-reflector) Also see: [Is there a “free” alternative to .NET Reflector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876347/is-there-a-free-alternative-to-net-reflector) and [Something Better than .NET Reflector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646707/something-better-than-net-reflector).

Comment: Check this blog post: http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2011/Feb-04.html

Answer (score 8):

Check [**ILSpy**](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ilspy.ashx), Development started after Red Gate announced that the free version of .NET Reflector would cease to exist by end of February 2011.

Also read their blog posts [here](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/dsrbecky/archive/tags/ILSpy/default.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

The last thing i heard was that JetBrains will ship a disassembler with resharper and also as standalone.

[Edit]
See http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/tag/resharper-6/

Comment: True. In fact, a free standalone JetBrains decompiler called [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) has just been released to Early Access Program, and [ReSharper 6](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+6.0+Nightly+Builds) has been available for early evaluation for several months.