# Best tool to decompile a C# .Net 1.1 application

Tags: c#, .net-1.1, decompiler

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A .net disassembler/decompiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578883/a-net-disassembler-decompiler)
>   [Is there a “free” alternative to .NET Reflector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876347/is-there-a-free-alternative-to-net-reflector)

A good while ago we wrote C# .NET 1.1 application for a customer and during the process of office moves and redundancies, the source code was not checked into Source Safe.

The customer has now reported an issue and we don't want to rewrite the app from scratch.

I believe we should be able to get the source code by decompiling the executable. Can anyone recommend a good tool to use (preferably a free one).

As we wrote the application in the first place, I don't expect there to be any legal issues with decompiling but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Why does it have to be free? It seems that you are saving a lot of money by not having to rewrite the application. You can afford to loose 100 dollar on a tool.

Comment: Either way, take a look at RedGate Reflector. It isn't free (anymore), but I'm still using the free 6.0 edition. Not a day goes by that I don't use it.

Comment: I don't think decompiling .net 1 is any different from decompiling newer versions of .net. And there are plenty of questions about that. Personally I use ILSpy, but since RedGate's licensing mistake, there are plenty of decompilers.

Comment: You won't get "the source code". You may get *some* source code which will compile to equivalent code. That's not the same thing though - don't expect any comments, and if you've only got the release binary you may not have local variable names etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of 2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876347/is-there-a-free-alternative-to-net-reflector 3) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646707/something-better-than-net-reflector 4) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425973/open-source-alternatives-to-reflector

Comment: @Steven It has to be a free tool as the company is run by a tight fisted **** who doesn't see the value of software. It would take a month of paperwork before I get told it's not worth the money. Ho Hum.

Comment: @TeamWild: Time to look for an other employer. Your company is doomed to fail.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Usually I use dnSpy or ILSpy.

You can try one of the following **.Net decompiler** (listed in no particular order)

- [**dnSpy**](https://github.com/dnSpy/dnSpy) --- C# / VB / IL --- https://github.com/dnSpy/dnSpy
- [**JustDecompile**](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) --- C# / VB / IL --- http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx
- [**ILSpy**](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy) --- C# / IL --- https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy
- [**dotPeek**](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler) --- C# / IL --- http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler
- [**.NET CodeReflect**](http://www.devextras.com/decompiler) --- C# / VB / IL --- http://www.devextras.com/decompiler
- [**DisSharp Decompiler**](http://netdecompiler.com/) --- C# / VB / IL --- http://netdecompiler.com/
- [**Assembly Analyzer**](http://asmanalyzer.codeplex.com/) --- http://asmanalyzer.codeplex.com/

Here are also some **IL decompiler** for the real hardcore developer :-)

- [**Dotnet IL Editor**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dile/) --- http://sourceforge.net/projects/dile/
- [**MSIL Disassembler**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) --- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

You may also find some useful information on these answers:

- [Something better than .NET Reflector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646707/something-better-than-net-reflector)
- [Open Source Alternatives to Reflector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425973/open-source-alternatives-to-reflector)

Comment: We used ilspy in the end. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

try [dotpeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/)