# Finding the namespace of a C# dll while using it in VB 6.0 through exporting it as .tlb file

Tags: c#, vb6, com-interop

I have to check the namespaces in a C# dll in a vb6.0 application. I am using "TypeLibInfo" to obtain the information of the dll. I am able to check the class name and method name but not the namespace.
How to obtain namespace of the DLL?

Comment: That's going to be difficult, COM Automation doesn't have the concept of namespaces.  Just a library name, nothing else.

Comment: +1 @HansPassant. Ishan, you could write a .Net method that uses reflection to find the namespaces. Make the .Net method COM-visible and you can call it from VB6. You might like to consider how important this is to you - can you live without it?

Comment: @MarkJ. Thanks Mark, I'll try it this way. Since its quite important so I have to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to Visual Studio, you can use the [Object Browser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exy1facf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to view the Namespaces, classes etc within an assembly.

If you don't, you might need to use a tool like [Reflector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876347/is-there-a-free-alternative-to-net-reflector), [CodeReflect](http://www.devextras.com/decompiler/) etc to do this.