# Reverse engineer a .NET SQL Assembly

Tags: c#, .net, dll, assemblies, reverse-engineering

What are some applications/software that can reverse engineer a .NET SQL assembly .DLL?  I already know about Reflector, doPeek, and JustDecompile but am looking for other ones.

Comment: Why do you need others? What features are you looking for?

Comment: What are your requirements that are not already met by those tools?

Comment: ReSharper 6 does this now as well...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425973/open-source-alternatives-to-reflector

Comment: just testing them all out as trying to find one that works to decompile, then allows be to recompile the dll and install correctly on my server

Comment: Was this a CLR dll? If you are only looking to re-install it, [CREATE ASSEMBLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189524.aspx) has an option for recreating it from the bits in sys.assemblies. Also, you might look at sys.assembly_files (I think?) if the dll was installed via Visual Studio, it might have also stored the source code in addition to the actual assembly. Ping me if you need help on that front

Comment: possible duplicate of [Something Better than .NET Reflector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646707/something-better-than-net-reflector)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ILDasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). The tool that's built into the framework.

I found most on here on [google](http://www.google.co.nz/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=.net%20decompilers).

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend [ILSpy](http://www.ilspy.net).

It's an open source alternative in response to latest versions of .NET Reflector no longer being free.

It's under active development, can decompile IL to C# (and VB in development 2.0 branch) and has some support for plugins.

Answer (score 1):

[ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ilspy.ashx) worked for me perfect.  Shows all the code and I copied and pasted right from the GUI into notepad and ta-da.  Good to go.  I'm not sure, however, if it had been obfuscated if it'd work as well.

Answer (score 0):

ok, reverse engineering may be illegal. if you really want to do it, you may use free/open source tool like ILSpy, and could also use commercial product like Xenocode Fox etc.