# Kentico ECommerceContext.CurrentShoppingCart for guest and authenticated user

Tags: kentico

Is it possible to have the same ECommerceContext.CurrentShoppingCart object returned irrespective of whether the user is logged into Kentico or not ? Currenty the object and consequently the contents of the of the shopping cart changes when the user logs in or out.

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box functionality to override this behavior. I definitely wouldn't recommend to override UserInfo.IsPublic(). You'll have to create your own class and re-implement the CurrentShoppingCart property. Have a look in the source code or use some [.NET reflector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646707/something-better-than-net-reflector) to see the actual implementation. As far as I can see there are no private members that you wouldn't be able to access so it should be piece of cake.

Answer (score 0):

You can set or clear the CustomerID associated with the Cart on log in/log out respectively if you want to synchronise the state of the cart with the identity of whoever is/isn't authenticated.