# How to examine .NET assembly without using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, dll, reflection, roslyn

Let's say, we have class `Base`, and `Derived`, defined in `Base.dll` and `Derived.dll` respectively. `Derived` is derived from `Base` (may not be a direct sub-class though)

The problem at hand is, if we have `Derived.dll` at hand but `Base.dll` is missing, how to programmatically examine all the types in `Derived`? e.g. to know what types are available, their accessibility, inheritance relationship, etc

Based on my understanding, reflection (things in `System.Reflection` namespace) is not an option here because `GetTypes()` will try to load `Base.dll` which is not available, thus throw `ReflectionTypeLoadException`.

In particularly, is this something that can be easily achieved using `Roslyn`, or some good library?

Comment: I guess that it is not possible. .NET assemblies don't directly implement the types of base classes in order to support Polymorphism.

Comment: You'd probably have to use Mono.Cecil for this. Roslyn is the compiler not a metadata reader (but obvs it has to read metadata to do compilation). You won't be able to work out all relationships though? What if there is an interface implemented by a base class. You don't have that type info because the assembly is not available.

Comment: Perhaps this thread may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646707/something-better-than-net-reflector

Comment: Have you tried [Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0et80c7k(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @elchido Once I call ``GetTypes()`` on an assembly loaded with ``ReflectionOnlyLoad``, it will still try to load all its dependencies, so ReflectionOnlyLoad is not an option here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For investigate .NET assembly (types, methods etc.) you need to get that from the metadata. `Roslyn` its not what you are looking for.

Although it's not exactly true, because Roslyn has two types of information about your code, one is nodes and token and the other is symbols. The first don't know about relation info but the second know.

Anyway, you can do it in more than one way. I'll write two of them.

1. Use [Mono.Cecil](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mono.Cecil/) to open your assembly, get the main module and investigate whatever you want.

   ```
   var allTypesDefinitaion = ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(assemblyPath).Types;
   ```
2. Use tools like [CFF Explorer](http://www.ntcore.com/exsuite.php) to investigate the relevant metadata tables. (TypeDef\Ref)

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for [System.Reflection.Metadata](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reflection.Metadata), which exposes assembly metadata directly, without loading assemblies via reflection.