# .NET Assembly viewer wanted

Tags: .net

I need a .NET assembly viewer which can show low-level details such as metadata tables content, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dot net assembly viewer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320272/dot-net-assembly-viewer)

Comment: @adatapost, possibly you need to read question carefully before writing?

Answer (score 7):

[ildasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1(VS.80).aspx), the IL disassembler, has low-level managed metadata token information.  It gets installed as part of the Windows SDK when you install Visual Studio.  It should be accessible from a VS command prompt.

When you open a managed assembly, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> or do View » MetaInfo » Show! to see the metadata tokens, e.g.:

```
TypeDef #1 (02000002)
-------------------------------------------------------
    TypDefName: ConsoleApplication1.Program  (02000002)
    Flags     : [NotPublic] [AutoLayout] [Class] [AnsiClass] [BeforeFieldInit]  (00100000)
    Extends   : 01000001 [TypeRef] System.Object
    Method #1 (06000001) [ENTRYPOINT]
    -------------------------------------------------------
        MethodName: Main (06000001)
        ...
```

There are also options to view the raw metadata tables via `ildasm /text /metadata=raw foo.dll`:

```
// =================================================
// 25(0x19): MethodImpl           cRecs:    0(0), cbRec:  6(0x6), cbTable:     0(0)
//   col  0:* Class        oCol: 0, cbCol:2, TypeDef
//   col  1:  MethodBody   oCol: 2, cbCol:2, MethodDefOrRef
//   col  2:  MethodDeclaration oCol: 4, cbCol:2, MethodDefOrRef
// =================================================
// 26(0x1a): ModuleRef            cRecs:    0(0), cbRec:  2(0x2), cbTable:     0(0)
//   col  0:  Name         oCol: 0, cbCol:2, string 
// =================================================
// 27(0x1b): TypeSpec             cRecs:    0(0), cbRec:  2(0x2), cbTable:     0(0)
//   col  0:  Signature    oCol: 0, cbCol:2, blob  
// ...
```

Comment: @user536232: see my updated answer.  It looks like ildasm can dump the raw metadata tables in text format.  I don't know how intelligible this is, but I know ildasm is kept up-to-date with the shipping compilers.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try RedGate's reflector?
http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/

Comment: can't find that functionality in version 7

Answer (score 2):

Check out

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/asmex.aspx

Comment: Nice tool, does what I need. Bit it's very old, doesn't support many new features. Is there any new version?

Answer (score 1):

[Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) will do that. It will show resources as well as metadata information on methods, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is an application CFF Explorer which will show you the metadata directories, PE header and all that other good stuff.

Available from: http://www.ntcore.com/exsuite.php

Answer (score -1):

I think its already build-in in Visual Studio 2008 or use

**NDepend**

NDepend is a Visual Studio tool to manage complex .NET code and achieve high Code Quality. With NDepend, software quality can be measured using Code Metrics.

[NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com)

Comment: what has NDepend got to do with assembly metadata tables? Pretty sure the answer is "nothing, nothing at all"